# Filter ListView which is loaded from PagerAdaper in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am using [this](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax) project and edited it in my way. I used a common layout for every page. There is a ListView in that layout. I am checking the position of the page and setting different view to it depending on that position.

There is an editText in my actionbar. I want to filter the listview of the current page according to the onTextChanged of the editText. Everything is working fine but the filtering is not happening.

Here is my full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static TextView actionbarTitle;
    public static EditText listViewEditText;
    public static ImageButton listViewSearch;
    public static Context context;
    public static ListView songslist;
    public static final int MAX_PAGES = 1;

    private int num_pages = 5;
    public ArrayList<String> title;
    public ArrayList<Long> albumId;
    public ArrayList albumName;
    public ArrayList songs;
    public ArrayList artist;
    public ArrayList songsPath;
    public ArrayList songsDuration;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        context = this;

        populate();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customactionbar, null);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
        listViewSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch);
        listViewEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        actionbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_left);

        listViewSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                actionbarTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                listViewEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        final ViewPagerParallax pager = (ViewPagerParallax) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.set_max_pages(MAX_PAGES);
        pager.setBackgroundAsset(R.drawable.picture);
        pager.setAdapter(new my_adapter());

        pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            num_pages = savedInstanceState.getInt("num_pages");
            pager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page"), false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("num_pages", num_pages);
        final ViewPagerParallax pager = (ViewPagerParallax) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        outState.putInt("current_page", pager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    private class my_adapter extends PagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return num_pages;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return view == o;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            View new_view = null;

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            new_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
            songslist = (ListView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            if (position == 0) {
                songslist.setAdapter(new CustomListViewSongs(context, title, artist, songsDuration));
            } else if (position == 1) {
                songslist.setAdapter(new CustomListViewSongs(context, songsDuration, artist, songsDuration));
            } else if (position == 2) {
                songslist.setAdapter(new CustomListViewSongs(context, songsPath, artist, songsDuration));
            }


            listViewEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                    int length = listViewEditText.getText().length();
                    temp.clear();
                    for (int t = 0; t < title.size(); t++) {
                        if (length <= title.get(t).length()) {
                            if (listViewEditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) title.get(t).substring(0, length))) {
                                temp.add(title.get(t));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    songslist.setAdapter(new CustomListViewSongs(context, temp, artist, songsDuration));

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
            container.addView(new_view);
            Log.e("TAG", "" + position);
            return new_view;
        }
    }


    private void populate() {

        ArrayList<Long> albumId = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList artist = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList title = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList album = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList songs = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList songsPath = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList songsDuration = new ArrayList();


        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
        };

        cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            artist.add(cursor.getString(1));
            songsPath.add(cursor.getString(3));
            songs.add(cursor.getString(4));
            songsDuration.add(cursor.getString(5));
            album.add(cursor.getString(6));
            albumId.add(cursor.getLong(7));
            title.add(cursor.getString(2));
            //songUri.add(cursor.getString(3));
        }
        cursor.close();
        this.title = title;
        this.albumId = albumId;
        this.albumName = album;
        this.songs = songs;
        //this.songs = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.songsPath = songsPath;
        this.songsDuration = songsDuration;
        //Collections.sort(this.songs, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        //Collections.sort(this.albumName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use Autocomplete textView.